# when for_each empty, ignore dynamic resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following in my main.tf:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "task_role_policy" {
  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.policy_statements
    content {
      actions   = statement.value.actions
      resources = statement.value.resources
      effect    = "Allow"
    }
  }
}
```

When var.policy_statements is empty list or nothing I get the following error when running `terraform apply`:

```
Error: Error creating IAM policy dev-chatbot-engine-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Syntax errors in policy.
    status code: 400, request id: a181b065-b659-4261-87d5-9aae8c4454aa

  on .terraform/modules/service/main.tf line 68, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "task_role":
  68: resource "aws_iam_policy" "task_role" {
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the resource?

Comment: There isn't resource code. the block dynamically generates `aws_iam_policy_document` but my `var.policy_statements` could be empty or nothing. It should skip generating any `aws_iam_policy_document` but instead it errors

Comment: It looks like this error is coming from the remote IAM API during the apply step when creating that IAM policy named "task_role". Are you able to see the `policy` value for that resource in the plan output before applying it and getting this error? If so, it would help to share the full plan for that `aws_iam_policy.task_role` resource in your question to see what exactly the `aws_iam_policy_document` data resource is generating here, and thus what the IAM API might be objecting to.

Comment: When `var.policy_statements` is nothing or empty, I don't want to generate any `policy` so it shouldn't call IAM API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this policy is still being reference in the `aws_iam_policy.task_role` resource when `var.policy_statements` is empty.

This would cause `aws_iam_policy.task_role` to be created with an empty `Statement` (which causes that malformed-policy error you are seeing).

I would recommend setting a `count` flag on the policy itself so that it doesn't even attempt to create it when the statements are empty, e.g.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "task_role" {
  count = length(var.policy_statements) == 0 ? 0 : 1

  // Your other args here...
}
```

This may have cascading effects to other resources (such as those that consume `aws_iam_policy.task_role`). You'll need to handle those effects by providing defaults that don't break or adding a `count` there as well.

Comment: Yes, that’s how we fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more concise version of stevemao's answer

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "task_role" {
  count = min(length(var.policy_statements), 1)

  // Your other args here...
}
```